# When shall I define polymorphic functions by type classes or by some other ways?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, adhoc-polymorphism

I am trying to figure out the purpose of type class, and what else is there if not using type class.

Is type class   a way to define polymorphic functions?

Is type class the only way to define polymorphic functions? For example:

```
class Eq a where
    (==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x /= y  =  not (x == y)

instance Eq Bool where 
    False == False  =  True 
    True  == True   =  True 
    _     == _      =  False
```

Can I define `==` and `/=` for `Bool` (and any other type) without using type class `Eq`?

Where there is any other way, when shall I use which way to define polymorphic functions, by using type class or by using the other way?

Comment: That's the only way to achieve that kind of polymorphism, but of course there are still functions like `id :: a -> a` which are polymorphic in a very different way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always write *unconstrained* polymorphic function, that doesn't require any typeclass. A simple example is

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

– this works without a typeclass, and (well, *because*) it works for *any type* `a` whatsoever. Namely, `length` doesn't actually care what the *values* in that list are, it only cares about the *structure* in which those values are contained. It never actually does anything with those values themselves, and the polymorphic type actually guarantees that.

If the polymorphic task you need is of this form, i.e. a type that you don't actually need to access, you just know *it's there*, then you should not write/invoke a type class, just use ML-style parametric polymorphism as in `length`. However, quite often you *will* need to access the values themselves, inspect them in some way. Doing that without however limiting you to a particular concrete type is what type classes are there for. `Eq`, as you quoted yourself, is an example.

Comment: Thanks. Is type class the only way to overload functions in Haskell?

Comment: Depends on what you call “overload”. It is possible to have _different functions with the same name_ in different modules, but you can't use those polymorphically (basically, the names are qualified/separated already during parsing, like with variables of the same name in different scopes). Polymorphic-overloading does indeed require typeclasses, so if that's what you want then a class is the right thing to use.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "use those polymorphically"?

Comment: Invoking them by the single name and having the compiler (or runtime) figure out which implementation to use, based on the types.

Answer (score 6):

> Is type class a way to define polymorphic functions?

**Yes**, it is *a* way. But not the only way. For example *parametric polymorphism* simply means that if you define a function like `init :: [a] -> [a]`, it will work for any `a`. Type classes are used for *ad-hoc polymorphism*: depending on the type, the implementation can be entirely different. This in contrast to *parametric polymorphism*, where the `head` function is always the same, regardless the type for `a`.

> Is type class the only way to define polymorphic functions?

**No**, see the previous section.

> Can I define `==` and `/=` for `Bool` (and any other type) without using type class `Eq`?

That depends on whether the implementation is the same for all types or not. You can use the [**`-XNoImplicitPrelude`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.2/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#id598783) flag to avoid importing the `Prelude`, and then you can define your own `(==)` function.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between polymorphic fuctions in OOP and in haskell, I say it because the term "polymorphism " is usually used in OOP.

Functions over list, by example, are polymorphic:

```
cons:: a -> [a] -> [a]
cons x xs = x:xs
```

where a is the polymorphic type, and there is no typeclass there.

By the way, there is a way to implement quickly typeclasses, by default, such as `Eq` or `Show`, by example:

```
data MBool = MTrue | MFalse deriving (Eq, Show)
```

So, the difference is that the typeclass is a constraint, imagine this function with lists:

```
mapShow :: Show a =>  [a] -> [String]
mapShow = map show
```

That's different, because now, a is restricted, it can't be any "a". It should implement the typeclass `Show`.

In conclusion, you can see that `a` type in `cons` function is more generic or abstract than `Show => a -> a`  type in `mapShow` function.